# unable to export a double data type number in .CSV

Tags: php, csv, double

I have a number as `009103744779100000007284` when I try to export into .csv it is converting into exponent form.

**EDIT**

As per the comments below, I tried to open with Excel but when I format the cell number itself getting changed. Actual number should be '009103744779100000007284'

[image]

Comment: Haven't faced the specific data type problem but something similar, are you sure it's not the program's fault? (the programm you use to open the .csv)

Comment: Don't open it in Excel?

Comment: Yeah, sounds like Excel trying to be *helpful*...

Comment: As an aside: I'm guessing, by the fact the username is *magento_bee* you're generally working on Magento - in which case, get Open Office and use Calc whenever you're working with Dataflow exports or similar - you'll suffer far less data corruption, especially when working with UTF-8.

Comment: Check the csv with notepad or similar, what does it show?

Comment: Thanks all @PedroLobito Yes when  I open this on notepad, it is showing proper number.

Answer (score 1):

I found the steps to get required result.

```
1. Open excel workbook
2. Open the Import Wizard (Data -> From Text)
3. Select your .csv file and Import
4. In the dialogue box, choose 'Delimited', and click Next.
5. Choose your delimiters as comma and uncheck othermoptions. And then choose your Text qualifiers as {None} in the dropdown section,
click Next
6. In the Data preview field select the column you want to be text. It should highlight.
7. In the Column data format field, select 'Text'.
8. Then click finish.
```

Comment: remark: your solution is not in adequation with title !

Comment: @schlebe do you need different problem, let me know, if I can i shall help you

Comment: No, I don't need different problem. I only say that your answer is not a solution to the problem described in title. You say that you are unable to export double data type in CSV and you solve that using an import in Excel. The correct title would be 'How to import code containing only digits into Excel file without losing some characters"

Answer (score 1):

To export double data type displayed with exponent (4.01924E+12), you must format the complete column to NUMBER before saving sheet into CSV file using Save As Excel functionality.

If this column contains some product codes, the non-significant zero are lost.

If non-significant zero are important and the size of the code is unknown, the only solution is to find an original file that contains full code STRING with all zeroes and to use solution proposed by Butterfly.